# React Intersection Observer on multiple elements

Tags: reactjs, intersection-observer

I have a code that uses react-intersection-observer below:
https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-observe-elements-ieoh8u?file=/src/App.js

I'm trying to find out which is the current image in view, and when you scroll down to middle of page where both `Image 1` and `Image 2` are in view, the indicator below keeps flickering between Image 1 and 2.

I want it to be link it won't switch to Image 2 until Image 1 is completely out of view.

How to achieve this?

Comment: The sandbox is not working. Please paste your code here.

Comment: It's working fine for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things causing problems in your code.

1. Page needs to be moved outside App component. It is now redefined on every render of the App component.
2. You need to use useEffect (or similar) hooks to track state changes. Otherwise these callbacks will be called on every render.
3. There needs to be way to track what images are currently visible and what are not.

I commented the changes below to make the code work:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useInView } from "react-intersection-observer";

import "./styles.css";

//Change no. 1: moved Page component outside App component
function Page({ data, onPageChange }) {
  const { ref, inView, entry } = useInView({
    threshold: 0
  });

  //Change no 2: moved in an useEffect and added inView as second parameter
  React.useEffect(() => {
    onPageChange(data.name, inView);
  }, [inView, onPageChange, data.name]);

  return (
    <div>
      {data.name} below
      <img ref={ref} src={data.image} alt={data.name} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  //Change no 3: wrapped data to useMemo
  const data = React.useMemo(() => [
    {
      name: "Image 1",
      image:
        "https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/cdn-cgi/image/width=850/uploads/users/107/posts/26488/final_image/41-space-scrolling-background850-2.jpg"
    },
    {
      name: "Image 2",
      image:
        "https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/cdn-cgi/image/width=850/uploads/users/107/posts/26488/final_image/41-space-scrolling-background850-2.jpg"
    }
  ], []);

  const [inViewName, setInViewName] = React.useState(1);

  //Change no 4: Added help object to track visible images
  const [allVisible, setAllVisible] = React.useState({});

  //Change no 5: updating the allVisible object here with correct state
  const onPageChange = React.useCallback((name, inView) => {
    setAllVisible((old) => ({ ...old, [name]: inView }));
  }, []);

  //Change no 6: Finding first visible image and updating inViewName accordingly
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let firstVisible = data.find((img) => allVisible[img.name]);
    if (firstVisible) {
      setInViewName(firstVisible.name);
    }
  }, [allVisible, data]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map((page, i) => (
        <Page key={i} data={page} onPageChange={onPageChange} />
      ))}
      <div className="NameIndicator">{inViewName}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Please note that there might be easier ways to create this functionality. Maybe using refs and having all the logic on the App level for example.